# State hoisting in Kotlin onSearchChange: (String) -> Unit

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I am trying to use state hoisting in android

---

I am new to android development using jetpack compose

```
onSearchChange: (String) -> Unit,
onCategoryChange: (Category) -> Unit,
onProductSelect: (Product) -> Unit,
    
    
composable(Screen.Home.route) { MainPage(navController = navController, searchQuery = "",
                productCategories = categories, selectedCategory = Category("","",0),
                products = pros, /* what do I write here for the 3 lines above?? :( the onSearch,etc I have an error bc of them */
                )}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the answer, apologies, this is a bit long, as Ill try to share how I design my "state hoisting"

Lets simply start first with the following:

A: First based on the [Official Docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state)

> State in an app is any value that can change over time. This is a very
> broad definition and encompasses everything from a Room database to a
> variable on a class.
>
> All Android apps display state to the user. A few examples of state in
> Android apps:
>
> - A Snackbar that shows when a network connection can't be established.
> - A blog post and associated comments.
> - Ripple animations on buttons that
>   play when a user clicks them.
> - Stickers that a user can draw on top of
>   an image.

B: And personally, for me

> "State Hoisting" is part of "State Management"

Now consider a very simple scenario, We have a `LoginForm` with 2 input fields, and have its basic states like the following

- Input will be received from the user and will be stored in a mutableState variable named `userName`
- Input will be received from the user and will be stored in a mutableState variable named `password`

We have defined 2 requirements above, without doing them, our `LoginForm` would be stateless

```
@Composable
fun LoginForm() {

    var userName by remember { mutableStateOf("")}
    var password by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .wrapContentSize()
    ) {

        TextField(
            value = userName,
            onValueChange = {
                userName = it
            }
        )

        TextField(
            value = password,
            onValueChange = {
                password = it
            },
            visualTransformation = PasswordVisualTransformation()
        )
    }
}
```

So far, everything is working but nothing is "Hoisted", their states are handled inside the `LoginForm` composable.

State Hoisting Part 1: a `LoginState` class

Now apart from the 2 requirements above, lets add one additional requirement.

- Validate user name and password

  - if login is invalid, show Toast "Sorry invalid login"
  - if login is valid, show Toast "Hello and Welcome to compose world"

This can be done inside the `LoginForm` composable, but its better to do the logic handling or any business logic in a separate class, leaving your UI intact independent of it

```
class LoginState {
    var userName by mutableStateOf("")
    var password by mutableStateOf("")


    fun validateAction() {
        if (userName == "Stack" && password == "Overflow") {
            // tell the ui to show Toast 
        } else {
            // tell the ui to show Toast
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun LoginForm() {

    val loginState = remember { LoginState() }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .wrapContentSize()
    ) {

        TextField(
            value = loginState.userName,
            onValueChange = {
                loginState.userName = it
            }
        )

        TextField(
            value = loginState.password,
            onValueChange = {
                loginState.password = it
            },
            visualTransformation = PasswordVisualTransformation()
        )
    }
}
```

Now everything is still working and with additional class where we hoisted our **userName** and **password**, and we included a `validation` functionality, nothing fancy, it will simply call something that will show Toast with a string message depending if the login is valid or not.

State Hoisting Part 2: a `LoginViewModel` class

Now apart from the 3 requirements above, lets add some more realistic requirements

- Validate user name and password
- if login is invalid, show Toast "Sorry invalid login"
- if login is valid, call a `Post` login `network` call and update your `database`
- if Login is success from backend sever show a Toast "Welcome To World"
- But when the app is minimized you have to dispose any current network call, no Toast should be shown.

Take note that the codes below won't simply work and not how you would define it in a real situation though.

```
val viewModel = LoginViewModel()

data class UserLogin(
    val userName : String = "",
    val password : String = ""
)

class LoginViewModel (
    val loginRepository: LoginRepository
) {

    private val _loginFlow = MutableStateFlow(UserLogin())
    val loginFlow : StateFlow<UserLogin> = _loginFlow

    fun validateAction() {
        // ommited codes
    }

    fun onUserNameInput(userName: String) {
    }

    fun onPasswordInput(password: String) {
    }
}


@Composable
fun LoginForm() {

    val loginState by viewModel.loginFlow.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .wrapContentSize()
    ) {

        TextField(
            value = loginState.userName,
            onValueChange = {
                viewModel.onUserNameInput(it)
            }
        )

        TextField(
            value = loginState.password,
            onValueChange = {
                viewModel.onPasswordInput(it)
            },
            visualTransformation = PasswordVisualTransformation()
        )
    }
}
```

But that's the most top level state hoisting you can do where you would deal with network calls and database.

To summarize:

- You don't need to consider hoisting up your mutableStates if its just a simple composable doing simple thing.
- But If the logic gets bigger consider using a `State Class` like the `LoginState` class to make your UI independent of the business logic.
- If you have to perform some network calls, database updates and making sure such use-cases are bound to a `LifeCycle`, consider using a `ViewModel`

Another thing to mention but out of topic is when you are hoisting states, there is a thing called scoped `re-composition` where you want a specific composable to get updated without affecting the others around, it is where you will think your composable designs on how you would handle mutableStates.

Answer (score 0):

To put it into simple terms, state hoisting is having your state variables in the outer most composable possible, this gives you access to said states in multiple functions, better performance, less mess and code reusability!
Hoisting is one of the fundamentals of using Jetpack Compose, example below:

```
@Composable
fun OuterComposable(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier    
) {

    // This is your state variable
    var input by remember { mutabelStateOf("") }

    InnerComposable(
        modifier = Modifier,
        text = input,
        onType = { input = it } // This will asign the string returned by said function to the "input" state variable
    )
}

@Composable
fun InnerComposable(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
    text: String,
    onType: (String) -> Unit
) {

    TextField(
        modifier = modifier,
        value = text,
        onValueChange = { onType(it) } // This returns what the user typed (function mentioned in the previous comment)
    )
}
```

---

With the code above, you have a text field in the "InnerComposable" function which becomes usable in multiple places with different values.
You can keep adding layers of composables, important thing is to keep the state variable in the outermost function possible.

Hope the explanation was clear! :)